# dot character in property name

Tags: javascript, object, properties, naming

I got this code snippet from  [jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavepropertykeypath-value).
In the example, one of the variables is named `ceiling.height` and is the only variable with a dot `.` in the name. What would be the purpose of using variables with a dot in the name such that it warrants this example in the documentation?

```
  const houseForSale = {
    bath: true,
    bedrooms: 4,
    kitchen: {
      amenities: ['oven', 'stove', 'washer'],
      area: 20,
      wallColor: 'white',
      'nice.oven': true,
    },
    'ceiling.height': 2,
  };
```

Comment: You should ask the authors of the documentation. At face value, it just makes life more difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose would be to store nested objects in a flat format, ie. a database table.
You could use something like [dottie.js](https://github.com/mickhansen/dottie.js) to transform this flat object into a nested object

```js
const values = {
  'user.name': 'Gummy Bear',
  'user.email': 'gummybear@candymountain.com',
  'user.professional.title': 'King',
  'user.professional.employer': 'Candy Mountain'
};
const transformed = dottie.transform(values);
```

We would now find this to be the value of `transformed`

```js
{
  user: {
    name: 'Gummy Bear',
    email: 'gummybear@candymountain.com',
    professional: {
      title: 'King',
      employer: 'Candy Mountain'
    }
  }
}
```

Why they use it like that in the example seems to be so that they can provide an example (below) on how to access these kinds of variable names. Imagine that you wanted the `.toHaveProperty(keyPath value?)` function from the [Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavepropertykeypath-value) to operate on a property in the `values` object from the above example. This shows you how you might use this function with such a property.

```js
// Referencing keys with dot in the key itself
expect(houseForSale).toHaveProperty(['ceiling.height'], 'tall');
```

Unless you have a very good reason, using these kinds of variable names is not a best practice and I would not recommend it. That said, while a variable name with a `.` character is not able to be used with dot syntax:

```js
houseForSale.ceiling.height = undefined
```

It is still accessible with bracket syntax:

```js
houseForSale['ceiling.height'] = 2
```

Comment: Perhaps, but the example is a nested object.

Comment: Agreed, that's why I added a reflection on its purpose in that particular example "It seems to be so that they can provide an example (below) on how to access these kinds of variable names"

So, imagine that that you were using the flat values object from my example with the .toHaveProperty() function from the Jest docs.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: that is clear. thank you for all participants.